# Mod Rewrite load index.php on bad path

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

These are the rewrite rules I'm using.  At this point I'm trying to force bad urls to load index.php.  The html tag `<base href="/directory-name/" />` is in the top of index.php, so my css, images and other assets are loading properly.

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /index.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?x=$1 [L]
```

Url Examples:

```
www.domain.com/directory-name/
www.domain.com/directory-name/index.php
www.domain.com/directory-name/index.php/arg1/arg2/arg3

www.domain.com/directory-name/anything-here
www.domain.com/directory-name/anything-here/arg1/arg2/arg3
```

The first 3 url examples work fine and load `index.php`.  But the 4th and 5th urls fail and dumps me back to the html root / where a xampp index exists.  I'm assuming the failure of the last url rewrite is because the index.php is in a sub-directory off of root?

How would I fix that?  How would I force the urls to load `www.domain.com/directory-name/index.php` even if something else is in the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?x=$1 [L]
```

Comment: For the bonus round how would you add custom error 404 if the file was extras-404.php?

Comment: Place `ErrorDocument 404 /extras-404.php` on top.

Comment: Provide me an example of some of those URLs?

Comment: It turned out to be a bug on my end.  Sorry.  I should have deleted that comment.